# Arduino Serial analogWrite

Tags: serial-port, arduino

How am I able to read the serial input on the arduino and write that value to an LED?
i.e. if I type `042` into my console, it should execute `analogWrite(led, 42);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(Serial.available()){
    int val = Serial.read();
    digitalWrite(led, val);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Start with this [tutorial](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Dimmer) then work your way up to looping over Serial.read to read in a line of text and use [int](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/IntCast) to convert the text to an integer.